# Why element with 100% width and displayed as table have right margin not work?

Tags: html, css, width, margin, css-tables

In the following code, when the row div is displayed as `table` and `width` set to 100%, the box shrinks and it seems the `margin-right` gets sets to nil or you can say that it doesn't show any affect.

However, When I remove `width:100%,`margin-right` gets applied

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.row {
  background-color: #cdecde;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row table">
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae autem minima minus eligendi, enim dicta quibusdam reiciendis veniam maiores accusamus ut, dolorum repellat, ea, odit quisquam magni dolor aliquid vero!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sp30xr76/

Kindly explain the above behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You are apply *negative* `margin`s to `row` element - this is causing the *problem* here:

When the *negative margins* are applied the `table` is shifted to the left taking up the space of the `padding` given to the `container` - try removing the *negative margins* from `row` and see how it nicely aligns horizontally:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.row {
  background-color: #cdecde;
  /*margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;*/
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.col {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row table">
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae autem minima minus eligendi, enim dicta quibusdam reiciendis veniam maiores accusamus ut, dolorum repellat, ea, odit quisquam magni dolor aliquid vero!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you don't give `width: 100%` the `table` takes the full *available width* because the content of `table` is a text that spans multiple lines.

See what happens when there is less text:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.row {
  background-color: #cdecde;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
}
.col {
  padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row table">
    <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that clears things up, thanks!